# How do i use multiple suggester in a single url in amazon cloudsearch ? or can i use multiple fields in a single suggester for the autocomplete?

Tags: amazon-web-services, autocomplete, autosuggest, amazon-cloudsearch

I am using Autocomplete feature from the amazon cloudsearch, As per the documentation there is an example for using just one suggester in the query parameter. Can it be possible to use more than one suggester?

Or Can I add multiple fields to look for in a single suggester I create? 
if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

This is very lame of Amazon but you cannot use multiple fields in a suggester and cannot use multiple suggesters per request. You have to issue multiple queries for each suggester and aggregate the results yourself! Come on, Amazon...

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/getting-suggestions.html

> If you want to get suggestions from multiple text fields, you define a
>   suggester for each field and submit separate suggestion requests to
>   get matches from each suggester. You can configure up to ten
>   suggesters.